# Store sql.eachRow() of groovy sql to a List

Tags: grails, groovy

do you know how to store the result from

```
    sql.eachRow()
```

of groovy sql to a list? for example def personList = [] ?

example:

```
    sql.eachRow('select lastname from users where id='active')
```

What I want is to store the result ie. lastnames to a list ie def personlist = [];
I know I can easily do this by namedQuery and I've already done it. But their is some underlying reason about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
def reqdColName = "lastname"
def query = "select $reqdColName from users where id='active'"
```

Straight option would be to use the [rows](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#rows%28groovy.lang.GString%29)() method.

```
def list= Sql.rows(query) //returns groovyrowresult as list
```

---

Another option is you could use the [executeQuery](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) instead, to get hold of the resultset of the query and thereby get an array/list on it.

```
def array = Sql.executeQuery(query).getArray(reqdColName)

//If you need as a list
def personList = Arrays.asList(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that the question has been asked a long time ago, but still, I feel the answer may be of help for someone out there.

```
  def personlist = []
    sql = Sql.newInstance(url, username, password, driver)
    query = "select $reqdColName from users where id='active'"
    sql.eachRow(query)
    {
       row-> personlist << row.toString()
    }
    sql.close()

    personlist.each{println it}  // you can also return the list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def personList = sql.rows("select lastname from users where id='active'")*.lastname
```